# Lua calling and read another script

Tags: node.js, lua

I have buy a script for autotouch which is running lua and js files. I would like to read the encrypted code for my safety. The script is updating every week by its creator but I want to watch the code for safety and learning.

How can I do that?

Comment: why would you buy and run encrypted code from people you don't trust in the first place?

Comment: because work better than mine

Comment: Show an example of encrypted code.

Comment: l have a .ate file.